# Default parameters for functions

Tags: c++

Say I have a function like the following in c++,

```cpp
int sum(int x = 0, int y = 0) {
    return x + y;
}
```

I can use the default value of y by calling the function like `sum(3)` which would then return 3. Is it possible to use the default value of x, and not y? I know I can call the function with the default value of x explicitly like `sum(0,4)`, but is there a way to call the function like `sum(y = 4)` which would then use the default value of x?

Comment: There are some libraries which allow named parameter to have your expected syntax or similar. You might look that article [Named Arguments in C++](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2018/12/14/named-arguments-cpp/).

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no way. A possible workaround is to use `std::optional`:

```
int sum(std::optional<int> x = {}, std::optional<int> y = {}) {
    return x.value_or(0) + y.value_or(0);
}
```

Then you can use `{}` or `std::nullopt` to use the default value: `sum({}, 4)`.

---

Note that if you pass `{}` to an `int` parameter (as opposed to `std::optional<int>`), it will always pass zero, regardless of what the default argument is.

Comment: that looks ugly tbh.

Comment: Well... at least it doesn't require the caller to know the default value by heart, thus less error prone.  That's pretty useful, like Python's `= None` idiom for default arguments.

Comment: @Raildex Beauty is in the eye of the beholder. You'll learn to love it.